# Marketing cloud SSJS, where to see debug

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Hello guys I have this code:

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try{
    var couponsDE = DataExtension.Init("9F69D084-64B5-4FAA-ACB4-D6CB5EBA5F02");
    var couponRows = couponsDE.Rows.Retrieve();
    Write("debug log" + "<br>");
} catch(err){
    Write("debug log err" + err + "<br>")
}
</script>
```

How can I check that "`write("debug log" + "<br>")`?" where it will print?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are missing a semicolon after your last `Write()` function. Also, you are not writing where you are executing this code. You will need to test this in a Cloud Page, as the SSJS Activity does not print the log anywhere, unless you add a function to insert this into a data extension:

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
    var couponsDE = DataExtension.Init("9F69D084-64B5-4FAA-ACB4-D6CB5EBA5F02");
    var couponRows = couponsDE.Rows.Retrieve();
} 
catch(err) {
    Write("debug log err" + err + "<br>");
    var today = new Date();
    var logEntryID = Platform.Function.GUID();
    var logInsert = Platform.Function.InsertData("ErrorLog",["errorUID","errorDate","errorMessage"],[logEntryID,today,err]);
}
</script>
```